# No Persistence provider for EntityManager named xxx

Tags: hibernate, maven, jpa, drools

Inside drools workbench i created java class to get entitymanager and i used inside drl files ,But my problem is that

1. when i create new project in workbench i create project structure like maven
2. the persistence.xml is inside src/main.resources/METE-INf/persistence.xml

when i call class to get entitymanager like bellow

```
package demo.test;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernateEntityManagerFactory;
import org.hibernate.Session;

/**
 * This class was automatically generated by the data modeler tool.
 */

public class Factory implements java.io.Serializable {

    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Factory() {
    }


public Session getSessionHibernate(){

  HibernateEntityManagerFactory ha = (HibernateEntityManagerFactory) Persistence
                .createEntityManagerFactory("flightdataunit");
        EntityManager emf = ha.createEntityManager();

        Session session = emf.unwrap(Session.class);

        session.beginTransaction().begin();
        return session;
}
}
```

And persistence.xml like bellow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:orm="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="flightdataunit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/sqlserver/flightdata</jta-data-source>
        <class>demo.test.Aircraftfleetdetail</class>
        <class>demo.test.Flightdatacrew</class>
        <class>demo.test.Airfield</class>
        <class>demo.test.FlightdatacrewPK</class>
        <class>demo.test.Flighttype</class>
        <class>demo.test.Repository</class>
        <class>demo.test.Seatconfig</class>
        <class>demo.test.Aircraftidentity</class>
        <class>demo.test.Place</class>
        <class>demo.test.Flightdata</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and pom.xml like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>TEST</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>TEST</name>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sqlserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>jarfile</artifactId>
      <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>antlr</groupId>
      <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.0.Final</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

when i tried to call Factory class i got 
no persistence provider for named XXX

new factory class

```
package demo.test;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernateEntityManagerFactory;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
/**
 * This class was automatically generated by the data modeler tool.
 */

@Stateless                                                                            
public class Factory implements java.io.Serializable {

    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName ="flightdataunit")
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public Factory() {
    }


public Session getSessionHibernate(){

        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);


        return session;
}
}
```

Comment: What environment are you trying to run it on? You are defining the persistence unit with transaction type equal to JTA, which means that container should be responsible for creating entity manager, but you are creating it manually yourself. Please read this: http://tomee.apache.org/jpa-concepts.html for more information

Comment: actually i'm using wildfly 8.1.Final application server,inside that kie-server and kie-wb wars are deployed ,i need hibernate session object to accesss data inside kie-workbench

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two different things. If you are using Java EE compliant application server you can actually inject the `EntityManager` using `@PeristenceContext` annoation. If you want to use JPA, don't try to create hibernate session (e.g. vendor specific implementation), and definitely do not start transactions on your own - use [container managed transactions](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html).

So you will need to

- make `Factory` a `@Stateless` session bean (or stateful, depends on usage)
- Inject `@PersistenceContext EntityManager em` in Factory
- In your code call methods of `em`, e.g. the EntityManager

This is a nice resource to put you right on track: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ejb/ejb_persistence.htm

Comment: ,by use of ejb, i have to write methods to access data inside interface then i impliment that , but i need hibernate session object to use named queries inside drools drl files like   FF:Flightdata( $flightNo:flightNo) from new Factory().getSessionHibernate().getNamedQuery("Flightdata.findAll").setParameter("flightNo", "5j-110").list();

Comment: In EJB3+ you don't need to write separate interface for EJB bean. When you really do need to use the hibernate session for named queries you can still inject the entity manager (as I wrote in the answer) and then unwrap the HibernateSession out of it.

Comment: **@rapasoft** i created datasource in wilfly server with jndi name java:jboss/sqlserver but when i tried to access data using hibernate session , null pointer exception i'm getting, the factory class is above

Comment: Yes, exactly. What you want is to use container managed entity manager, so why don't you just inject it as I've stated in my answer? You can read more about this here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/6nmq2cpbj/index.html 
I still don't understand why would you complicate things like this.

Comment: i did as you told, what is wrong in that code ?, actually i'm begginer for this , send the sample code

Comment: one this is that , i need hibernate session object  that one used in drl files ,  i don't want to write methods inside factory class as above

Comment: Please, try to read and understand the code example I have posted in the answer. Then you should read through JPA tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html because I think you are mixing everything at once without proper knowledge of it.

Comment: **@rapasoft** actually i'm not writing code in IDE(eclipse) , but inside kie-drools.war file that is deployed on wildfly server, still i'm getting error, one thing i need session object of hibernate or entitymanager inside war project plz tell me